# Timebased workflow rule, does it fire if the date is changed?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

There are a lot of questions about time based workflows here, but I didn't see the answer to mine.

I have a time based workflow rule. The entry criteria is true when a checkbox is checked. Now there should be a time based workflow, which unchecks this field, when a certain date is reached, like:

```
One hour after Customer_Protection_Date__c
```

Now my question is the following: If a user changes the Customer_Protection_Date__c, will the time based workflow still execute for the "Old" date? Or will it be updated and only fire when the new date is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only fire when the new date is reached, but only if that new date is in the future.

Extract from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245):

> What happens if I update the value of a date field used in a time
> trigger?
>
> Salesforce recalculates the time trigger as long as the time
> trigger has not yet fired and the recalculation does not reschedule
> the time trigger to a date in the past.
>
> Example: If a Workflow Rule
> alerts the Opportunity owner seven days before the Opportunity Close
> Date and the close date is set to 2/20/2008, Salesforce sends the
> alert on 2/13/2008. If you update the Close Date to 2/10/2008 and the
> current date is 2/2/2008 or before, Salesforce reschedules the alert
> for 2/3/2008. The evaluation date of pending actions is ALWAYS
> reevaluated and updated (if necessary) irrespective of the rule
> criteria. Of course, if the rule is evaluated to false, it does not
> matter as the actions are removed from the queue.