# Process builder scheduled action: does it fire if the criteria is changed but the record still meets the criteria?

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action, scheduled-flow

This question is similar to [Timebased workflow rule, does it fire if the date is changed?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80523/timebased-workflow-rule-does-it-fire-if-the-date-is-changed) but slightly different as this is referring to a process builder scheduled action.

In a Process Builder, if I have a criteria that says '*if the opportunity is created/edited and the stage name is X, then send an email is 7 days*' and then opportunity A goes into the time based workflow queue and the **next day**, I update the stage name of opportunity A to 'Y' but also update the criteria rule to 'Y', then does opportunity A *still* stay in the time-based workflow queue unchanged (i.e. due to trigger the email send in 6 days)?

I have been reading the documentation and it seems that it does because although the criteria has changed, the record still meets the criteria although the criteria has changed.

Comment: [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343642/do-scheduled-paths-get-evaluated-canceled-when-record-triggered-flow-version-cha/343643#343643) that might shed some insight

Comment: You're probably aware but I'd still want to mention: if this is a new Process Builder, please consider building it as a Flow. You will be much more flexible and also SF is no longer actively promoting Process Builder. Here's how to do this in Flow: https://automationchampion.com/2022/04/02/adding-a-time-dependent-action-to-record-triggered-flow-2/